# How do I see which processes have open TCP/IP ports in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, tcpip

How do I see which processes have open [TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_Suite) ports in [Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

One alternative is the use of the `lsof` utility; specifically, `lsof -i 4tcp` will list all processes with some sort of TCP IPv4 network sockets open. The manpage of `lsof` will provide you with detailed information on how to use the utility and how to interpret the output.

Answer (score 19):

If you are interested in a specific port, you can use this example:

```
lsof -i 4tcp:8080 -sTCP:LISTEN
```

If you would only like to get the process id, you can run this:

```
lsof -i 4tcp:8080 -sTCP:LISTEN -Fp
```

Comment: How to get historical data?

Answer (score 5):

I use the command below when I want to see everything that's on a specific port for either TCP or UDP. The `-n` option disables attempting to resolve the IP addresses into domain names, and the `-P` disables attempting to figure out the name of a particular port. Also, running as `root` will show you more processes than running as a normal user.

`sudo lsof -iTCP:53 -iUDP:53 -n -P`

Answer (score 1):

use this:
`netstat -p tcp -p udp`

together with this:
`lsof -n -i4TCP -i4UDP`

Comment: Welcome back to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.

Answer (score -1):

This should be possible in a terminal window using the [Netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) command.

And if you like the GUI way more:

> With Mac OS X 10.5, the
>   /Applications/Utilities folder
>   contains a network utility called:
>   Network Utility, see tab Netstat for
>   these stats presented in a gui
>   application, along with Ping, Lookup,
>   Traceroute, Whois, Finger and Port
>   Scan.

Comment: netstat on OS X has no options to list the processes sockets are attached to.

Comment: OSX 11 has now deprecated the Network Utiltiy